# How can I set the URL of a GridView SelectButton in ASP?

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView that shows a table of results from a database.  I have the ShowSelectButton set to true, but the links always take me back to the page that the GridView is on.  How can I change the URL of the SelectButton to say UpdateItem.aspx?id=??? where ??? is equal to the ID of the db row?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="GetStudents" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConn %>" SelectCommand="dbo.GetStudents" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="StudentGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="studentId" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="firstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="StudentGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="StudentId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int studentId=0;
   int.TryParse(GridView1.SelectedValue, out studentId);
   Response.Redirect("~/UpdateItem.aspx?id=" + studentId);
}
```

Perhaps you can consider trying some like above and see if that helps.

Comment: I get the following error: Message 1 Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'SelectedIndexChanged' is not a valid attribute of element 'GridView

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Sorry there was a typo. The correct attribute's supposed to be `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the `CommandField` by a `TemplateField` with a HyperLink or a LinkButton:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/UpdateItem.aspx?id=" + Eval("ID") %>' Text="Select" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Even better `<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("ID", "~/updateitem.aspx?id={0}")%>' Text="details"></asp:Hyperlink>`
Note: this is _not_ SelectButton anymore. As well as in the answer.

Comment: @AlexanderKudryashev  Yes. I mentioned that he could use a LinkButton or a HyperLink and showed the first one. I will replace it by the HyperLink, which is preferable, effectively. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just missed this part of your comment.
To say truth, I hate PostBackUrl.